# Order by NSDate a NSMutableArray containing NSObjects that contain NSDates

Tags: ios

My object "Event" has got a property `NSDate`.
I fill a `NSMutableArray` with "Event" objects.
Is there a way to order by `NSDate` the members of my `NSMutableArray`?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an NSMutableArray

```
[yourArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Event *obj1, Event *obj2){
     return [obj1.date compare:obj2.date];
}];
```

Otherwise :

```
NSArray sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Event *obj1, Event *obj2) {
    return [obj1.date compare:obj2.date];
}];
```